# Arduino IDE on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, arduino

I want to ask whether it is possible to install arduino ide or avr-tools to ubuntu touch. Is it ?

Comment: You say that I can install arduino with that way ? I need actually more solid answer because it contains avr-tools which ubuntu-touch might not support. I am not sure that it will work. If you are sure let me know

Comment: No we're not saying that we're absolutely sure that you can install the Arduino IDE that way: we're saying that the question you're asking is extremely similar the the above question, so try that out first and then feed back here.

Comment: Yes, you can install avr-tools that way. Depending on the device you are using, you may also be able to use Libertine to install the GUI IDE in a container.

Comment: thx for your answer dobey, it is what I want to know. Fabby I don't have an ubuntu touch tablet or smartphone, so I cannot try it. I am asking because I am planning to buy.